# Getting Empty datapoints from Cloudwatch when fetched via boto3 in Lambda function

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using below code to retrieve data from cloudwatch:

```
                startTime = datetime(datetime.now().year,datetime.now().month,datetime.now().day) - timedelta(days=1)
                endTime = startTime + timedelta(days=1)
            client = boto3.client('cloudwatch',region_name=tunnelDetails["Region"])
            while startTime <= endTime :
                    response = client.get_metric_statistics(
                    Namespace=tunnelDetails["Namespace"],
                    MetricName=tunnelDetails["MetricName"],
                    Dimensions=[
                        {
                            'Name': 'InstanceId',
                            'Value': tunnelDetails["InstanceId"]
                        },
                    ],
                    Period=60,
                    StartTime=startTime,
                    EndTime=startTime + timedelta(days = 1),
                    Statistics=['Average'],
                    Unit='Percent'
                    )
```

It had worked before, but suddenly datapoint is coming as empty list. There is no change in config file. It is for CPUUtilization. Could someone please help. I am able to see datapoint via AWS CLI.

aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics 
--namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization 
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value="i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
--statistics Average 
--start-time "2021-03-15 00:00:00" 
--end-time "2021-03-16 00:00:00" 
--period 60 
--region 'us-west-1'